# Compressed index sectionindextitlesfortableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

Loaded up my App in iOS7 SDK. My index list for my tableview is now compressed:

[image]

I can't seem to track down what could be going on. I don't set a size or length anywhere. Below is my code that assign the titles, but I'm guessing the problem must be somewhere else?

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (BookHasSections())
    {
        NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;

        for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++)
        {
            switch (section)
            {
                case 0:
                    [titleArray addObject:@"1"];
                    break;
                default:
                    [titleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d0",section]];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return titleArray;
}
```

Comment: I think that's just the way iOS 7 present section index titles by default now. I agree it's not really the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I've since observed the appearance in other Apps. I don't understand how some UI designer sat in his chair thinking, "You know, this index would look better if it were shorter."

Comment: Did this ever get a solution?  The contacts app doesn't have this problem...

Comment: Not that I know of. Whether it is actually a bug I am still not sure. According to @MarkoNikolovski it is an iOS7 feature. You do make a good point with the Contacts App though. Although I would say that I noticed the contacts items have "dot" characters in between each letter. The Music App is the same way. Not sure of any Apple Apps that might use a numbered list instead of an alphabetical?

Comment: @BenRobinson Do you know of any Apple apps that use a numbered list (instead of alphabetical)?

Comment: Can't think of any; not sure it's important - the dot is used when there isn't enough space to display the whole list (kinda like ... in text).  My app has around 200 entries in the index, so I get these dots - still it only takes up the same space as pictured